# How to handle storage objects referencing other storage objects?

Tags: c#, json, azure, serialization

Consider a billiards application. One type of model you might want is a `Match`, which references multiple `Game` objects, which each `Game` object containing the scoring data for that game.  Of course, both `Match` and `Game` references `Player`, as you need to know who is playing. So given this relatively simple model:

```
class Match
{
    Player Player1;
    Player Player2;
    List<Game> Games;
}

class Game
{
    Player Player1;
    Player Player2;

    // ... scoring data
}

class Player
{
    string PlayerName;
}
```

We want to save our match to some storage (type is unimportant, but for example, lets say we are storing blobs of JSON serialized objects in Azure).

The easy way we might do this is:

```
storage.SaveBlob(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myMatch));
```

But this will save multiple copies of `Player1` and `Player2` - one for the match, and one for each game played in the match.

We could change `Game` to:

```
class Game
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    Player Player1;

    [JsonIgnore]
    Player Player2;

    // ... scoring data
}
```

This solves our duplicate Player problem, but now we have the issue that deserialization would require `Match` to fix the data members of all its referenced `Game` objects, along with any other similar objects in a more complicated scenario.

We could again update `Game`:

```
class Game
{
    [JsonIgnore]
    Match Match;

    [JsonIgnore]
    Player Player1 => Match.Player1;

    [JsonIgnore]
    Player Player2 => Match.Player2;

    // ... scoring data
}
```

This simplifies the problem, but still requires `Match` deserialization to fix its properties. Also, adding this type of abstraction creates the problem that `Game` objects *must* by part of a `Match`. Conceptually this isn't the case (there's no reason you couldn't have a `Game` not part of a full `Match`), so this seems like a poor approach.

A different option might be to change `Match` to:

```
class Match
{
    Player Player1 => Games.First().Player1;
    Player Player2 => Games.First().Player2;
    List<Game> Games;
}
```

This sort of solves our problem of having `Player` objects saved it multiple classes, but it will cause a great deal of data duplication. Also, if we save all this data to storage, and then the `Player` changes their rating level, for example, we *usually* want to have all the references to be updated as well (there are cases where this might not be the case, but let's ignore for now).

The goal is to have clean serialization/deserialization while maintaining some amount of data normalization. So...what should be done?  Is this not a common problem?

Comment: This is a very broad question with many possible answers (with many types of data storage available - relational, column, key/value, graph, document) and many brands of databases within those categories.

Comment: You aren't wrong, but a question with several right answers isn't bad. I'm happy to hear any that fit the scenario :)

Answer (score -2):

This is a good job for a relational database.

Store entities (Matches, Games, Players) in separate tables.

Retrieve them using "join" operations.

What you're proposing is to re-invent that wheel, which has been around for decades.

On the other hand, it looks like you're storing historical data, which is not going to change, so a non-relational database (NoSQL) might be the thing for you.  Storage is exceedingly cheap, so don't fret a little duplication of data here and there (since it won't be changing).

Note: if you application might allow stored data to change, then duplicated data is *evil* and should be avoided at all cost (so nobody ever updates one copy but not the others), use a relational model in that case.

Comment: Relational model is fine; the data storage is somewhat irrelevant for this issue, but lets say I am using SQL. The question then: given a `Match` object, how can you easily save the entire thing to the database without data duplication?  The real question is: Given an object O which is to be represented in the database, but itself referencing other objects that are also stored in the database, how can you save and load O consistently without creating a lot of type specific infrastructure on what load/store operations entail.

Comment: Duplicated data is *not* evil - it's called *denormalized* data. And serves a purpose. And should *not* be avoided at all cost. This is a very "normalized relational" point of view (and an opinionated one, at that).

Comment: Also: I don't understand your assertion that this data belongs in a relational store, yet if it's historical / non-changing, then it should go into a NoSQL database. Why? And which NoSQL type: Document? Key/value? Column? Graph? And why relational in the first place vs, say, graph or document?